# Hexdump format syntax - color

Tags: colors, hexdump

I'm trying to display a hexdump of a file and highlight carriage returns in red. I'm having a really hard time understanding the format of the formats option (-e).

Is it something like:

```
hexdump -e "_L[red:0A]" practice_file_1.txt
```

?

I'm slowly solving the puzzle, but I probably don't know a higher level knowledge base that would make this more understandable, like the printf(3) syntax or something, but I don't know what it is...

Also, is it even related to the -L tag? (Do I need to use the -L option?)

References:

- [the “FORMATS” section in `hexdump(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html#FORMATS);
- [`fprintf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html).

Comment: The `_L` has to follow a format-specifier, e.g., `%c`.  The examples at the end of the hexdump manual page show this.

Comment: Do you have an example of a command that would work?

Comment: Not offhand, but if I had that version of hexdump, perhaps interesting (which system are you using?  I don't see the color version in Debian)

Comment: The reason I asked is that I have tried a lot of different formats that didn't work, including adding the %c. I'm using Fedora, not sure if that is the system though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

```
hexdump -f foo.cfg foo.log
```

and foo.cfg contains

```
"%06.6_ao "  12/1 "%3_c_L[red:0x0a] "
"\n"
```

and the result only colors when writing to a terminal (not redirected).  Looking at the result by capturing the output using `script`, the result looks like this in a text editor:

```
Script started on Fri 04 Nov 2016 09:23:32 PM EDT
000000   f   o   o ^[[31m \n^[[0m   f   o   o   .   l   o   g ^[[31m \n^[[0m^M
000014   s   d   d   m   -   a   u   t   h   0   2   4^M
000030   0   b   f   b   3   -   a   d   0   6   -   4^M
000044   7   0   7   -   b   a   1   3   -   1   f   e^M
000060   0   7   5   9   e   a   e   7   4 ^[[31m \n^[[0m   s   d^M
000074   d   m   -   a   u   t   h   0   b   1   9   9^M
000110   b   f   5   -   c   7   3   4   -   4   5   f^M
000124   f   -   a   4   8   0   -   f   5   a   a   c^M
000140   e   c   3   e   1   b   0 ^[[31m \n^[[0m   s   d   d   m^M
000154   -   a   u   t   h   4   0   7   1   d   2   1^M
000170   b   -   6   0   4   7   -   4   a   8   5   -^M
000204   8   1   3   6   -   f   3   8   9   0   d   6^M
000220   a   b   a   d   0 ^[[31m \n^[[0m   s   d   d   m   -   a^M
```

Comment: Oh!!! I didn't realize the format options were in a .cfg file! I thought that they were put after the -e option in terminal. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: in -e, you can only do simple things

Comment: With `-e` (`--format`) you can do the same things as with the format file, just repeat the option. E. g. `-e '"%06.6_ao"' -e '12/1 "%3_c_L[red:0xa]"' ...`. Note, you should use single quotes for the format string and double quotes for format rules inside format strings. That is: `-e ' " " '`.